# Ternary operator (alternatives)

Tags: abap

Is there a ternary or conditional operator available in the ABAP syntax? I haven't found one so am assuming that the answer is no but is there then an alternative that I can use to clear up the common "dumb" `IF` statements that I routinely use?

For example, consider a method that logs a message with optional message parameters. To decide between using the imported parameter or the default I have to check the value like so:

```
IF iv_class IS INITIAL.
    lv_message_class = 'DEFAULT'.
ELSE.
    lv_message_class = iv_class.
ENDIF.
IF iv_number IS INITIAL.
    lv_message_number = '000'.
ELSE.
    lv_message_number = iv_number.
ENDIF.
IF iv_type IS INITIAL.
    lv_message_type = 'E'.
ELSE.
    lv_message_type = iv_type.
ENDIF.
```

A ternary operator would reduce each of these five-line statements to a single line as seen in the below code block. It could even make the use of a temporary variable unnecessary when the operator is used in-line.

```
lv_message_class  = iv_class  IS INITIAL ? 'DEFAULT' : iv_class.
lv_message_number = iv_number IS INITIAL ? '000'     : iv_number .
lv_message_type   = iv_type   IS INITIAL ? 'E'       : iv_type   .
```

Is there a way to approximate this kind of programming style in ABAP or am I stuck with the clutter?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Release 7.40** brings a whole bunch of ABAP improvements which I'm finding heaps interesting. The ternary style declaration (at least something that resembles it) is one of them

Syntax:

```
COND dtype|#( WHEN log_exp1 THEN result1 
            [ WHEN log_exp2 THEN result2 ] 
            ... 
            [ ELSE resultn ] ) ...
```

Example data declaration of a variable called 'bool' and a conditional value assignment in one line. Old skool ABAP this will take like 10 lines.

```
DATA(bool) = COND #( WHEN i * i > number THEN abap_true ELSE abap_false ).
```

More info: http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2013/07/22/abap-news-for-release-740

Comment: Having moved to 7.4 I can confirm that this works perfectly, even though the syntax highlight will mark parts of the statement in invalid red. As a note, this is not restricted to declaring new variables, any value assignment can use the `COND` statement.

Comment: Hey, what about `Data(bool) = xsdbool( i * i > number ).`? This is not a ternary but it's pretty short (for ABAP at least)

Answer (score 2):

No, in ABAP there is no operator similar to the construct `a ? b : c` known from other languages. In your concrete example, however, you could declare default values for your method parameters `iv_class` etc. in the method's signature.

Answer (score 1):

While declaring the variables you can set the default value or explicitly do the same as below.

```
lv_message_class = 'DEFAULT'.
lv_message_number = '000'.
lv_message_type = 'E'.

IF iv_class IS NOT INITIAL.
    lv_message_class = iv_class.
ENDIF.
IF iv_number IS NOT INITIAL.
    lv_message_number = iv_number.
ENDIF.
IF iv_type IS NOT INITIAL.
    lv_message_type = iv_type.
ENDIF.
```